# Python, Pandas : Return only those rows which have missing values ...those only that satisfy a condition

Tags: python-3.x

Dataframe

```
      Name   Age     City   Experience
a     name1  34.0   Mumbai         5.0
b     name2  31.0    Delhi         NaN
c     name3  16.0   Mumbai        11.0
d     name4   NaN    Delhi        15.0
e     name5  33.0    Delhi         4.0
f     name6  35.0    Delhi         NaN
g     name7  35.0    Delhi        11.0
```

How can I calculate missing values in Experience column from the basis on Delhi city.
Output Should be of Delhi city : 2

Answer (score 0):

What about ?

```
df.groupby('City')['Experience'].isna().sum()
```

Comment: Ok..Thanks..but city should be equal to Delhi then it should be count